# How to get exact value of \leftmargin

Tags: margins, geometry

I need to extract the exact length of my left margin at a specific page in the document but `\leftmargin` doesn't seem to provide the correct value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\newlength{\oneinch}
    \setlength{\oneinch}{1in}
\begin{document}
    \the\leftmargin\par
    \the\oneinch
\end{document}
```

When testing, although I set it to 1in with `geometry` when I print `\the\leftmargin` I end up with 25.00003pt whereas one inch should be 72.26999pt. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`\leftmargin` is the wrong length. That is used for lists. You either need to calculate it from `\oddsidemargin`, or use the macro from geometry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\newlength{\oneinch}
    \setlength{\oneinch}{1in}
\begin{document}
\the\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin\relax
\makeatletter \Gm@lmargin\makeatother
\the\oneinch
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the "leftmargin" is `\oddsidemargin` plus `1in` (as you do in the code), users who may never have seen the drawing of the layout settings in LaTeX might not understand it. Otherwise +1 for a god answer

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply!  Maybe I wasn't clear in my post, but I was looking for a way to figure out the current margin without "knowing" what the margin is, and whether it was declared with `geometry` or some other way.

Comment: @daleif Oh, I just saw your comment.  So the `\the\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin\relax` does exactly that?

Comment: Just one more follow-up to make sure I understand correctly:  So the `\oddsidemargin plus 1in` always gives me the distance from left paper margin to text, wherever I am, even if odd/even pages have different margins, correct?

Comment: No, \oddsidemargin is for odd pages. On even pages you should use \evensidemargin. Also while the 1in is traditional, it can be changed (the value is stored in \hoffset).